# 4-table query with one LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I am developing an application that will help me equalize overtime.  I need to retrieve a list of all staff members that meet a certain criteria (Staff.OT_Eligibility=1) within a given time period (OT_Shift.OT_PeriodID=4) as well as the total number of shifts that they have been offered in that period.  The following query pulls the correct results but does not include any staff members that have 0 total shifts offered.

The problem I'm having is that the columns that I need returned in the query are separated by two intermediate tables.  For each shift of OT, there multiple staff members who are eligible and each staff member who is eligible for that shift may have one of 7 different response codes (each with a different value assigned for calculating the equalization).  This forces a relationship from Staff->OT_Shift->OT_Shift_Roster->OT_Response.

I've tried including "LEFT JOIN" on each JOIN statement hoping maybe it was just evaluated in the opposite order and that didn't change the result set.

```
SELECT 
    s.Staff_ID,
    s.LastName,
    sum(ResponseValue) AS Shift_Count
FROM Staff s
LEFT JOIN OT_Shift_Roster sr
    ON s.Staff_ID=sr.RosterID
JOIN OT_Response otr
    ON sr.Response=otr.OT_Response_ID
JOIN OT_Shift ots
    ON sr.ShiftID=ots.Shift_ID
WHERE
    s.OT_Eligibility = 1 AND ots.OT_PeriodID=4
GROUP BY s.Staff_ID
```

I'm getting the following but I'm missing about 20 more staff members that have 0 in the "Shift_Count" field.

```
# Staff_ID, LastName, Shift_Count
3, Kantner, 1
10, Wells, 2
12, Moore, 1
46, Denomy, 1
48, Costanzo, 1
49, George, 2
50, Schusterman, 2
51, O'Connor, 1
55, McLeod, 2
59, Potter, 1
69, Tristan, 1
75, Gardull, 1
77, Weis, 1
106, Thomasson, 1
107, Lehmann, 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to turn all `JOIN`s that depend on the `LEFT JOIN`ed table to `LEFT JOIN`se to the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`. `COALESCE()` (or the-like on your RDBMS) can be used to return `0` instead of `NULL` when no record matches in the `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    s.Staff_ID,
    s.LastName,
    COALESCE(SUM(ResponseValue), 0) AS Shift_Count
FROM Staff s
LEFT JOIN OT_Shift_Roster sr
    ON s.Staff_ID=sr.RosterID
LEFT JOIN OT_Response otr
    ON sr.Response=otr.OT_Response_ID
LEFT JOIN OT_Shift ots
    ON sr.ShiftID=ots.Shift_ID AND ots.OT_PeriodID=4
WHERE
    s.OT_Eligibility = 1 
GROUP BY s.Staff_ID
```

Rationale: conditions in the `WHERE` clause *must* be fulfilled for every record. But when the `LEFT JOIN` comes up empty, the condition can not be met, and the offending record is evicted from the resultset. In other words, putting a condition on a `LEFT JOIN`ed table in the `WHERE` clause implicitly turns it to an `INNER JOIN`. The same logic applies to an `INNER JOIN` that depends on a `LEFT JOIN`ed table.

Comment: Spot on!  Thank you.  And thanks for providing the explanation so I know why it worked.

Comment: Welcome @Druck281!